# Google Cloud Run deployment not working using `gcloud` SDK CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, knative

I have a service created on Google Cloud run that I am able to deploy manually through the Google Cloud Console UI using an image on Container registry. But deployment from CLI is failing. Here is the command I am using and the error I get. I am not able to understand what I am missing:

```
$ gcloud beta run deploy service-name --platform managed --region region-name --image image-url
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [service-name] in project [project-name] region [region-name]
X Deploying...
  . Creating Revision...
  . Routing traffic...
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request has errors
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: spec.revisionTemplate.spec.container.ports should be empty
    field: spec.revisionTemplate.spec.container.ports
```

**Update 1:**
I have updated the SDK using `gcloud components update`, but I still have the same issue

Here's my SDK Version

```
$gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 270.0.0
beta 2019.05.17
bq 2.0.49
core 2019.11.04
gsutil 4.46
```

I am using a multistage docker build. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM custom-dev-image

COPY . /project_dir
WORKDIR /project_dir
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 \
  /usr/local/bin/go build -a \
  -ldflags '-w -extldflags "-static"' \
  -o /root/go/bin/executable ./cmds/project/main.go

FROM alpine:3.10
ENV GIN_MODE=release APP_NAME=project_name
COPY --from=0 /root/go/bin/executable /usr/local/bin/
CMD executable
```

Comment: Can you share the version of the gcloud SDK `gcloud version`? Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: Not sure if this is your case, but if you are trying to expose your configuration. I would suggest you follow this [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-pods-to-the-cluster). Please notice that `ports` is empty and `containerPort: 80` is what gets the value. Otherwise, please share more information about your configuration.

Comment: You need to update the CLI `gcloud components update`.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I've updated the questions with my SDK version and dockerfile

Comment: @JohnHanley updating the components did not help :(

Comment: @sllopis I am not using Kubernetes, not sure how your suggestion applies for Google Cloud Run. There is not custom configuration I am using, just a dockerfile

Comment: The error message description is `spec.revisionTemplate.spec.container.ports should be empty`, I found out that the `container` part is [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.serverless.v1alpha1#google.cloud.serverless.v1alpha1.RevisionSpec.FIELDS.google.cloud.serverless.v1alpha1.Container.google.cloud.serverless.v1alpha1.RevisionSpec.container). Also, check your `ports` array because you may have put some values in it and must be empty, as stated in the error message.

Comment: More info about `ports` can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.serverless.v1alpha1#google.cloud.serverless.v1alpha1.Container.FIELDS.repeated.google.cloud.serverless.v1alpha1.ContainerPort.google.cloud.serverless.v1alpha1.Container.ports)

Comment: @pcx I workaround by recreating service in Cloud Run then run deploy again. It's seem to be some issue with Cloud Run service.

Comment: facing the same problem here

Comment: in my case the build works with the cli however I cant deploy I use the ui for now to deploy the new version

Comment: @Juk I have opened an issue in the official tracker here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144069696. Please add any information to this issue that can be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @HadyRashwan Same here, I am deploying manually using the UI now. This is a really big breakage for a google service, despite it being in beta! yikes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in Cloud Run. It has been fixed and deploying with CLI is working for me now. Here's the link to the issue I had raised with Google Cloud which has a response from them https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144069696.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and I assume it was because I had older Cloud Run deployment that was created before I had ran `gcloud components update` since some update.

I was able to fix it by deleting the whole Cloud Run service (through the GUI) and deploying it from scratch again (via terminal). I noticed that the `ports:` definition disappeared from the YAML once I did this.

After this I could do deployments normally.

Comment: Now i facing this issue instead

Creating Revision...................interrupted
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Resource readiness deadline exceeded.

I'm not sure that 'gcloud beta run deploy' timeout is the cause ?? But when i rerun again it works, sound weird. 

Comment: Thank you. The same fix worked for me. After deleting and recreating the service, I can now push new revisions of the Cloud Run service from gcloud CLI.